# Can I add an anchor (#) to WordPress Permalink for Category Base

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, categories, permalinks

I've created a Category page with tabs, that sorts individual categories (essentially a filterable gallery).

When a user clicks on a category, they are currently directed to "/categories/lifestyle"

Is there a way I can adjust this so the link will actually be "/categories/#lifestyle" instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the name of the page? Example, if user is being redirected to a specific div with id of `lifestyles` using the ID tag, on say categories.html page... the link would look like ->  `"/categories.html#lifestyle"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting to another page, use the file hierarchy for the folder and add the html page.   EX `categories.html` or `categories.php` then add the specific id section you are redirecting to... `#lifestyle` -> `/categories.html#lifestyle`

```css
#top {
  width: 400px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="top" >The following code redirects on the same page, but if I were redirecting to a new page I would add the file path in the href down to the file extention of said page... EX: href="somewebpage.html#go_here"</div>
<a href="#go_here" target="_self">Go to HERE</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="go_here">HERE</div>
<div id="top"><a href="#top" target="_self">Back to the top</a></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. You're logic isn't wrong, but not what I'm looking for. 

I'm looking for a dynamic WordPress solution. On the main blog page, when someone clicks a category, they are sent to /categories/%category% and I need to most likely write a javascript solution to make it /categories/#%category%

Comment: I see, this may assist... https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/